# Flutter how to listen to websocket response?

Tags: websocket, dart, flutter

As we all know, flutter has an example of using websocket, but it just receive websocket response as stream, and just something like this:

```
new StreamBuilder(
  stream: widget.channel.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return new Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : '');
  },
);
```

What I am want is an async function which receives every websocket response and append the result to a list, so that the listview can be updated.

How to get the websocket response as text or json anyway?

**Update**: 
I know there are some method like stream.listen now:

```
widget.channel.stream.listen((data) {
  print("!!!!new msg: $data");
  var dataJson = json.decode(data);
  print(dataJson["content"]);
  // do something after received data
  setState(() {
    _allAnimateMessages.insert(0, newMsg);
  });
  newMsg.animationController.forward();
});
```

This can work in a page, but when enter that page again, there was an error says `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`. 
How to make the stream can be listened at every begaining, and then boradcast to many pages?

Comment: Have you tried returning ListView.builder inside StreamBuilder

Comment: If you write your websocket backend, you can make it return full list everytime it updates, than I can write you a solution for that. If it returns one item by one, than you need to create local list where you will append your snapshots, and than use listview builder

Comment: @Tree Hi, I am using websocket for chat, so that the return of server are one by one, I need the stream being listen, and broadcast to whatever page I need that stream(identify them with sender address), this is something just like chat app like telegram

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @stt106 Not yet, the websokcet recevied data many times, every time UI updates...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are closing your WebSocket connection when you leave the current widget. Inside your widget's `State` class you should have a `dispose()` method that looks like this:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  widget.channel.sink.close();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: If that page closed, how to receieve at other page? (in case I am build a chat app, messages should be received everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

> What I am want is an async function which receives every websocket
>   response and append the result to a list, so that the listview can be
>   updated.

You need to manage this yourself in your state class.

```
final list = List<Message>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new StreamBuilder(
    stream: myStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      list.add(/* extract message from snapshot */);
      /* build a widget with your list */
    },
  );
}
```

> when enter that page again, there was an error says Bad state: Stream
>   has already been listened to.. How to make the stream can be listened
>   at every begaining, and then boradcast to many pages?

Dart has [two kinds of streams](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams), single-subscription and broadcast streams. See more info about the [differences](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/broadcast-streams), and how to [create streams](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/creating-streams). Recommendations here will depend largely on your application.

That said, usually apis that return a stream default to single-subscription and then have the `asBroadcastStream()` alternative.

If that's not an option, you can create an intermediate `StreamController` that listens on your single-subscription stream and returns a broadcast stream, that the rest of your app should listen to.

Both of these options are outlined in the link above about creating streams.