# How can I parse json data from websocket server in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, websocket, real-time, stream-builder

The WebSocket server is supposed to shoot json data as soon as it goes up, and I want to create a StreamBuilder that updates the data as it shoots me FutureBuilder has received async and wait http.get, and how do I make a Stream for my stream builder?

Here is the futurebuilder when I receive information from http server!(for all information, no realtime)
I want to receive information like this by streambuilder from websocket server for realtime!

```
class BallInformationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BallInformationWidgetState createState() => BallInformationWidgetState();
}

class BallInformationWidgetState extends State<BallInformationWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<BallInformation>>(
      future: getHttpBallInfo(urlPrefix),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print('http data : ${snapshot.data}');
        print('http length : ${snapshot.data.length}\n');
        print('http type : ${snapshot.data[0].id.runtimeType}\n');
        BallInformation ballInfo = snapshot.data[0]; // 공하나 객체 선언 후에 for 문?
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
          child: Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${ballInfo.id}' : 'Loading...'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class BallInformation {
  int id;
  double speed;
  String result;
  Map trajectoryParameter;

  BallInformation(this.id, this.speed, this.result, this.trajectoryParameter);

  BallInformation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    this.id = data['id'];
    this.speed = data['speed'];
    this.result = data['result'];
    this.trajectoryParameter = data['trajectory_parameter'];
  }
}

Future<List<BallInformation>> getHttpBallInfo(String url) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  String responseBody = response.body;
  var dataS = json.decode(responseBody);
  List<BallInformation> ballInformation = [];
  // If I receive json(only one information
  ballInformation.add(BallInformation.fromJson(dataS));
  // If I receive json(List, more than 1 information)
  // for (var data in dataS){
  //   ballInformation.add(BallInformation.fromJson(data));
  // }
  return ballInformation;
}
```

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50479452/flutter-how-to-listen-to-websocket-response

Comment: Read this article [Work with WebSockets](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets)

Comment: I know this examples but I wanna update the datas async when it updates from server! These examples are work with send button!

Answer (score 0):

The standart method for this is `json.decode(snapshot.data)`. This will return a map of your json data in the request.